# Merging polygon with two (or more) adjacent polygons in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, polygon, merge, vertices

I have for example this:

[image: Example]

I want to create this:

[image: what I want]

Basically I want to cut the polygon on the left side in half and merge one half with the upper right polygon and the other half with the lower right polygon.

It should be cut with a line that is the closest path from where the three polygons share a vertex to the outer border of the left polygon.

Manually cutting and merging won't do due to the amount of features that need this kind of merging. I'm using ArcGIS 10 with the advanced license.

Comment: That example is more than just a little bit unclear, but it is clear that you'd have to this... what language an environment have uou chosen? What have you written so far?

Comment: English. If you look at the first picture you see that there are 3 polygons; let's call the left one "A", the upper right one "X" and the lower right one "Y". I want to split "A" into two polygons (A1 and A2) at the point where all three polygons (A, X, Y) share a corner/vertex in the middle. I then want to merge A1 with X and A2 with Y (although this step is not a problem as i imagine the eliminate tool will do the trick, the problem is automating the splitting of polygon A at the shared corner).

Comment: There are no natural language programming options for ArcGIS. Once you start coding, you'll see that the problem is identifying the shared corner in the first place. In the meantime, you can **edit the question** to clarify the problem, as per GIS SE policy.

Answer (score 1):

"Manually cutting and merging won't do due..."

Even though my suggestion is manual, I think it should work:

You can merge any selected polygons in an edit session with the "merge" command. I created a command specifically for merging as I do edits often. 
Customize--> Customize mode--> Commands tab--> Click Keyboard at bottom--> In the Show commands containing window type merge--> Under Categories click Editor--> Click Merge... in Commands window--> then create a shortcut in the Press new shortcut key window (I did Ctrl+M)--> You should then see the shortcut in the Current Key/s window--> Close windows. You should now be able to select any amount of poylgons (from the same layer only!) and merge them.

Comment: Hello and thanks for commenting. I'm afraid you misunderstood my problem. Merging itself is not an issue, the issue is that I have one polygon (let's call it polygon "A") that shares borders with two other polygons ("X" & "Y"). X and Y also share a border between themselves. 
I want to cut polygon A

Comment: ... I want to split polygon A into two pieces and merge on piece to polygon X and the other to polygon Y. Try to look at my example pictures with this in mind and maybe it will become a litte clearer.

Answer (score 1):

In an edit session you have a [merge](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/creating-new-features/merging-features-in-the-same-layer.htm) command that works if you select 2 features from the same feature class (and only that feature class). You also have a split tool ([cut polygons](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/editing-existing-features/splitting-a-polygon.htm)) that works if you have one (and only one) feature selected in a single editable feature class. Therefore you can split first and then merge or merge first and then split. Whichever way you want to approach it.

So following your comment select polygon A and split it. Then select polygon X and the part of A that you want to merge with X (use the shift key) and merge them together. Then select the remaining piece of A and also select (use the shift key again) polygon Y and merge those two.

Save your edits and you are done.

Comment: Thanks for commenting! Sadly manual editing like you suggested would be quite time consuming due to the amount of data. Like I stated in the end of my post: "Manually cutting and merging won't do due to the amount of features that need this kind of merging.".

Comment: I think maybe I should create vertex points where polygons "X" and "Y" share a corner (like in my example) and points on the outer border of polygon "A" (I found a "create points on line" tool), then find a tool which can create a line from the X&Y vertex point to the closest polygon "A" point and then use this line for cutting. Like I said, there are lots of polygons like polygon "A" that need to be cut and merged to neighbouring polygons.